# Display VB.NET WPF window

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Sorry for this extremely amateur question, but I cannot make this work. I want to make a custom font dialog window (just for the heck of learning how it would be done) and from what I have found using Google, I should create an instance of the window I want to show and then call the Show() or ShowDialog() methods. However the intellisense popup does not show such methods as available and indeed the code does not compile and complains that those methods don't exist. Is there something really simple I am missing or am I just way off ?

```
Imports System.IO

Class MainWindow
    Public font_dialog As Window1 = New Window1

    // ... Removed code that was not pertinent

    Private Sub menu_font_Click(sender As System.Object, e As _
        System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles menu_font.Click
        // does not compile
        font_dialog.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Here is the exact error message:

> Error 1   'Show' is not a member of
>   'WpfApplication1.Window1'.    C:\Users\notmyrealusername\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\MainWindow.xaml.vb  24  9   WpfApplication2

XAML for Window1:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Window1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="453" Width="600" DataContext="{Binding}">
    <Grid >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="575*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TabControl Height="429" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="TabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="576" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <TabItem Header="Paramètres généraux" Name="TabItem1">
                <Grid>
                    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,14,0,0" Name="ComboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" />
                    <Label Content="Police" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,14,0,0" Name="Label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <Label Content="Styles" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,43,0,0" Name="Label2" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                    <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,43,0,0" Name="ListBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="213" SelectionMode="Multiple" />
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: So sorry. I have added the error message.

Comment: What is Window1?  That's where the problem lies - the compiler can't find a definition for Show() in Window1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'Show' is not a member of 'WpfApplication1.Window1'.

That mans your `Window1` is not a (valid) Window ...

Post the first lines of the XAML and the code behind.

Also, you probably want to call ShowDialog(), but that is a separate issue.

Comment: As Henk and I said, Window1 is a UserControl (note the opening <UserControl...). Refer to my answer for how to create a window, or just change the root from UserControl to Window and then the inheritance in the code behind file from UserControl to Window.

Comment: Ahh.. And your Window turns out to be a UserControl. Change it or (easier) create a new Window2.

Comment: Meh. I tell Visual Studio to make a new window and it makes code for a new control... '-__- Real logic right there VS.

Comment: Great. Changed "UserControl" to "Window" and it worked. Thanks. I'll give the check mark to Henk as he was the one who pointed out the "UserControl" error.

Answer (score 3):

You must make Window1 inherit from [Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx), which has the Show method. In Visual Studio, you can right click the project you want to add the window to and click Add -> Window.

Comment: That's how I created it in the first place.

Comment: Then there must be an issue with your VS. Nevertheless, as I stated in my comment under Henk's post, you can just change UserControl to Window both in XAML and the code behind file.